# Can I find out who is tracking my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, find-my-iphone

I received 3 emails from Apple that my phone was tracked using Find My iPhone. It gave the dates and times.  Can I find out who is tracking me using Find My iPhone ?

Comment: I would first suggest you to change your iCloud password now.

Comment: Yes I have changed my password

Comment: I just logged into my own phone to find it and received an email 10 minutes later...I think it's something new they are doing and there are probably some bugs to kink out while they do it

Answer (score 1):

Well it's someone who has you mail & password. You won't be able to know more.

If you don't know who did it, change immediately your password !

Comment: Actually, someone has your Apple ID and password, and is (was) using it to log on to iCloud or the Find my iPhone app.