# hackers - tracking my iphone

Tags: find-my-iphone

I've received 7 emails from Apple that my phone was tracked using Find My iPhone, can I call apple and find out who the device belongs too? I've already changed my password.

Comment: see this http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/147128/46541

Answer (score 0):

1. Change your password (to make sure whoever is logged in can't change it).
2. Go to [icloud.com](http://icloud.com/).
3. Go to `Settings`.

   [image]
4. Click "Sign out of all browsers currently logged in."
5. Change your password again (by now, they should be logged out).

As far as calling Apple to find out who did this, it is unlikely they will be able to tell you. You can try and call at `1-800-MY-APPLE`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Reset your "Find my phone"

iCloud: [Remove your device from Find My iPhone](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH2702)

Then enable it again after 15 or more minutes.

Check for emails from Apple.

Also there might be a bug in iOS 8.0.1 so just turn it off for now (and do not loose your phone).

Turn off "Find My iPhone" on your phone if you're using the feature. You can do this under Settings > iCloud > Find My iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

I was told by Apple they cannot find out but that you should change your password and make it something difficult with uppercase, numbers and symbols

I just logged into my own phone to find it and received an email 10 minutes later...I think it's something new they are doing and there are probably some bugs to kink out while they do it...hope this helps...I am not concerned on my end anymore and will just wait and see if it happens again.